# php8 - Use Associative Array in Match Expression

Tags: match, php-8

I really need to use `associative array` in `match` expression. Because, I can use the `associative array` for another purpose..

Example (what I expected):

```
$rank = [
    '1' => 'Beginner',
    '2' => 'Intermediate',
    '3' => 'Expert',
    '4' => 'Super Pro',
];

match ($user->rank) {
    ($rank), // This is what I expected, but it is not working
    default => 'N/A',
};

// why I want to be able to use associative array?
// because I can use the `$rank` variable for another purpose
// example

foreach ($rank as $each_rank) {
    // bla bla bla
}
```

.
.

Currently what I did is:

```
match ($user->rank) {
    '1' => 'Beginner',
    '2' => 'Intermediate',
    '3' => 'Expert',
    '4' => 'Super Pro',
    default => 'N/A',
};

// so now, this is quite anoyying
// because now, I need to write same code TWICE
// now, for another purpose, I need to write once again the same data

$rank = [
    '1' => 'Beginner',
    '2' => 'Intermediate',
    '3' => 'Expert',
    '4' => 'Super Pro',
];

foreach ($rank as $each_rank) {
    // bla bla bla
}
```

.

I hope you can understand my question and can help... Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Just simple like that :

```
$rank = [
    '1' => 'Beginner',
    '2' => 'Intermediate',
    '3' => 'Expert',
    '4' => 'Super Pro',
];
    
$expressionResult = match (true) {
    in_array($user->rank, array_keys($rank)) => $rank[$user->rank], // This is what I expected, but it is not working
    default => 'N/A',
};

echo $expressionResult;

// why I want to be able to use associative array?
// because I can use the `$rank` variable for another purpose
// example

foreach ($rank as $each_rank) {
    // bla bla bla
}
```

or more simple :

```
$rank = [
    '1' => 'Beginner',
    '2' => 'Intermediate',
    '3' => 'Expert',
    '4' => 'Super Pro',
];
    
$result = isset($rank[$user->rank]) ? $rank[$user->rank] : 'N/A';

echo $result;

// why I want to be able to use associative array?
// because I can use the `$rank` variable for another purpose
// example

foreach ($rank as $each_rank) {
    // bla bla bla
}
```